# Mysql Empty Post Error

Tags: php, mysql

```
  <form action="gonder.php" method="post">

        <fieldset>
            <label for="ad">Ad:</label>
            <input type="text" id="ad" placeholder="Tam Adınızı Giriniz" />

            <label for="soyad">Soyad:</label>
            <input type="text" id="soyad" placeholder="Soyadınızı Giriniz" />

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Adresinizi Giriniz" />

            <label for="mesaj">Mesaj:</label>
            <textarea id="mesaj" placeholder="Mesajınız"></textarea>
 <center></center>
            <center><input type="submit" value="Onaya Gönder" /></center>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

This one is my post form and this one ise gonder.php

```
 <?php
     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","yeniziyaretci");
     // Check connection
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }

     $sql="INSERT INTO mesajlar (ad, soyad, email, mesaj)
         VALUES ('$_POST[ad]','$_POST[soyad]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[mesaj]')";

     if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
     {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
     }
      echo "";

     mysqli_close($con);
     header("location:index.php?cmd=1");
  ?>
```

When I tried to post. They dont give eny error but they send it to mysql as a empty . Like this.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

Your `input` elements have no `name` attributes.
Also, please read up on the thing called 'sql injection'.

Answer (score 1):

You must select the inputs by name not by id.

change

`<input type="text" id="ad" placeholder="Tam Adınızı Giriniz" />`

to

`<input type="text" name="ad" id="ad" placeholder="Tam Adınızı Giriniz" />`

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong and insecure way to query your database. To get the one you have working, just change your `$sql` declaration as follows:

```
$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO mesajlar (ad, soyad, email, mesaj) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")', $_POST['ad'], $_POST['soyad'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['mesaj']);
```

But I would suggest you to learn ways to avoid mysql injection.

**EDIT**

And yes, you're missing `"name"` attributes on your form.

Answer (score 0):

Put this, it will work:

```
<form action="gonder.php" method="post">

        <fieldset>
            <label for="ad">Ad:</label>
            <input type="text" id="ad" name=="ad" placeholder="Tam Adınızı Giriniz" />

            <label for="soyad">Soyad:</label>
            <input type="text" id="soyad" name="soyad" placeholder="Soyadınızı Giriniz" />

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Adresinizi Giriniz" />

            <label for="mesaj">Mesaj:</label>
            <textarea id="mesaj" name="mesaj" placeholder="Mesajınız"></textarea>
 <center></center>
            <center><input type="submit" value="Onaya Gönder" /></center>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Either try

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mesajlar (ad, soyad, email, mesaj)
VALUES
('".$_POST[ad]."','".$_POST[soyad]."','".$_POST[email]."','".$_POST[mesaj]."')";
```

or

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mesajlar (ad, soyad, email, mesaj)
VALUES
('{$_POST[ad]}','{$_POST[soyad]}','{$_POST[email]}','{$_POST[mesaj]}')";
```

**EDIT**

Sorry I didn't notice but there is an issue in your html form too 
you need to have `name=""` attributes into you form elements as suggested by [Ø Hanky Panky Ø](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1570534/hanky-panky)

```
<form action="gonder.php" method="post">

    <fieldset>
        <label for="ad">Ad:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ad" name="ad" placeholder="Tam Adınızı Giriniz" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: That's not the only problem. Their input fields have no names in HTML and hence even after this fix this problem won't be resolved. Please consider updating your answer to cater for that as well